# Por que no funciona?, Cargar opciones en un select mediante otro select. AJAX LARAVEL 5.8

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax, laravel-5

estoy cargando opciones en un select mediate ajax y no encuentro la forma. Alguien me puede decir que esta mal?

Lo simplifique pero aun asi no carga:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12"> {{--ocupa todo el ancho del div--}}
                    <select id="categorias" name="categorias[]" value="{{ old('categorias[]') }}" multiple>
                        <option disabled selected>Dejar vacio para seleccionar todas</option>
                        @foreach ($categorias as $categoria)
                            <option value="{{$categoria['idcategoria']}}">{{$categoria['cat_descripcion']}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    <label>Seleccione a una o mas Categorias</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12"> {{--ocupa todo el ancho del div--}}
                    <select id="personas-categorias" name="personas[]" value="{{ old('personas[]') }}" multiple>
                        <option disabled selected>Dejar vacio para seleccionar todas</option>

                    </select>
                    <label>Seleccione a una o mas Personas</label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

---

```
            $('#categorias').on('change', function(){
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url:'people-by-category',
                data:{'categorias' : $('#categorias').val() },
                type:'post',
                success:  function (response) {
                    $('#personas-categorias').html('<option value="4"> asdasdasdasdasdadas </option>');
                },
                statusCode: {
                    404: function() {
                        alert('web not found');
                    }
                },
                error:function(x,xs,xt){
                    window.open(JSON.stringify(x));
                }
            });
        });
```

La idea es cargar response en #personas-categorias, como ven estoy cargando una opcion explicita y ni aun asi funciona.

Eh comprobado que response si tiene los datos que necesito, el problema es como cargar las opciones en el select #personas-categorias.

Comment: El ajax devuelve data en el response? si pones console.log(response); dentro del success te muestra algo?

Comment: si, muesta las copiones que tengo qe cargar en el select

Comment: Si pones en esa misma linea console.log($('#personas-categorias').length) que valor te muestra?

Comment: En todos los casos me muestra 1. Aunqe le agregue opciones en la vista  y #personas-categorias tenga dos opciones el console.log me muestra1